# jquery slider that wont show up after first call on a rails app

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, slider

I have a rails app that gives you a list of people.

1. When you click on a name, it shows you a div brought by an ajax call with a jquery slider bar, that you can adjust.
2. You can then close that div.
3. Should you open it again (for the same user), the ajax call goes back to retrieve the div with the slider
4. everything is there except for the slider bar. why?

Code:
inside the index.html, a div is called

```
<div id='relationships'>
  <%= render @relationships %>
</div>
```

the div has a partial. here is the partial _relationship.html.erb

```
<%= div_for relationship do %>
  <%= link_to image_tag('images/orange_man.jpg'), show_path(:id => relationship.id), :remote => true %>
<% end %>
```

when you click on the image 'orange man', the js request goes, up to the show action:

```
def show
  @relationship = Relationship.find(params[:id])
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.js
  end
end
```

and then since its a js call, the show.js.erb is called

```
$("#relationship_<%= @relationship.id %>").append("<%= escape_javascript(render 'knows_me')%>");
```

which has the knows_me partial called. the _knows_me.html.erb

```
<div id ="relationship_knows_me_#{@relationship.id}">

  <a class="close">X</a> 
  *****this is where you click to hide the div*****

  <% div_slider_id = "slider_knows_me_#{@relationship.id}" %>

  <%= form_tag('/relationships/update/', :remote => true) do %>

    <%= hidden_field_tag 'relationship_id', value = @relationship.id %>

    <div id="<%= div_slider_id %>" class="sliders"></div>

  <% end %>

</div>

<script type='text/javascript'>

$('a.close').on("click", function() {
    $(this).parent().slideUp();
  });

$(document).ready( function() {
  $(function() {
    $( "#<%= div_slider_id %>" ).slider({
      orientation: "horizontal",
      range: "min",
      value: <%= @knows_me %>,
      min: 0,
      max: 100,
      stop: function( event, ui ) {
        $( "#<%= amount_id %>" ).val( ui.value );
        $(this).submit();
      }
    });
 });
});
</script>
```

why does the slide show up only the first time? why it wont show up after i slideUp the div and request it again?.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

instead of using div id use div class. i was having same problem but it was solved after using div class

Answer (score 0):

turns out super engineer was kind of right. The id of the div was already there so since I hid it it wont show up again. I just changed the id of the div when getting the call back and problem solved.